# HyperV VMs randomly started freezing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, server-crashes

Got an odd situation I can't work out. HP Hypervisor running windows 2012r2 recently has started freezing the VMS. There are 4VMs on the hypervisor (all windows 2012r2). About once a week it seems the VMS all become unresponsive. They show as online in hyperv and the hypervisor stays responsive, however you can't get on the VMs using remote desktop OR connecting through hyperv manager. I can't see anything in the system/application event viewer that could point me in the right direction and i'm a bit stumped. Latest windows updates and drivers installed as far as I can tell.

I need a bit of input on how to debug this

Comment: You've checked also the event viewer of each VM's? Which model of HP Server is?